# Merge certain two range of lines

Tags: notepad++

I want to combine two sets of data into a set of records. The file looks like as follows.

```
Vehicle 1
Vehicle 2
Vehicle 3
Vehicle 4

Color 1
Color 2
Color 3
Color 4
```

I want the merged text as follows,

```
Vehicle 1 Color 1
Vehicle 2 Color 2
Vehicle 3 Color 3
Vehicle 4 Color 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with "Edit in column mode".

- Add some white spaces at the end of first vehicule line, to make it the largest line.
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and, simultaneously, select the color lines with the mouse.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**+**<kbd>C</kbd>
- Move the cursor at the end of the first vehicule line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**+**<kbd>V</kbd>